# Using CommonsMultipartResolver to parse an HTTP request with embedded multipart content

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to receive an HTTP request which has multipart content nested inside a multipart request as shown below. When using **CommonsMultipartResolver** as the resolver the **LinkedMultiValueMap** passed to the receiving service activator contains a map of all the parts but the imbedded multipart is an **UploadedMultipartFile** which contains the entire content. In the sample *boundary2----extKDvsqGExTQI2WVuplHFCUQJ3XVL* is the boundary of the embedded multipart.

How can I get the embedded multipart parsed into a **LinkedMultiValueMap** so that I can get the version and payload? Is it possible for the **CommonsMultipartResolver** to do this or is there another way to parse it?

***Http Request:***

> POST http://xxxxx:8087/edi846Inbound HTTP/1.1
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=DM1-Sb0636VXPQNO3412Ygegb9suqr
>   .......
>
> Content-Length: 2787
>
> --DM1-Sb0636VXPQNO3412Ygegb9suqr
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"
>
> Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Length: 7
>
> gisb-acknowledgement-receipt
>
> --DM1-Sb0636VXPQNO3412Ygegb9suqr
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input-format" Content-Type:
>   text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Length: 3
>
> X12
>
> --DM1-Sb0636VXPQNO3412Ygegb9suqr
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input-data"; filename="TEST-DTEBS_846_3563_10142015102600.x12"
>
> Content-Type:
>   multipart/encrypted;boundary=boundary2--extKDvsqGExTQI2WVuplHFCUQJ3XVL protocol:
>   application/pgp-encrypted
>
> boundary2----extKDvsqGExTQI2WVuplHFCUQJ3XVL
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="version" Content-Type:
>   application/pgp-encrypted Content-Length: 10
>
> Version: 1
>
> boundary2----extKDvsqGExTQI2WVuplHFCUQJ3XVL
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload" Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length:
>   1118
>
> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- Version: BCPG v1.47
>
> hQIOA8aa0/bci2e/EAf/fkgOBK+cOoeY+44htcvjE9Sxk9RK73aOEaxDOBNqFOsV
>   Nzw1va7cc7wzYOTlHhZV/MkpXq+IrZV316moJu1EAhscN9YmyReVDOzrkzZ1hBmq
>   V2MlAr5/CRqS7nQEmCqy/Mz0STtAPZNg3FOh8F79dJnRws5/SdW+zvn2MoSvGTs3
>   0YvjmtPq2YyVkMlAvJ62f903UYNIiAcEe1k8gWDVW9LJ4tGud+8H0bsG8EFWPsSI
>   b5rON+MKGykbWGnbSrOy9cqslJaghj91r7ZbsXXXiRn9v4rpOardfiBEnoamI5Tz
>   jfDKESnr7CqoZgb62je+NJrB5puoAwy8LTynXx4cmQgAnf8lb6f+mIxa1U1Mu6iR
>   KNTjrH83Cx2BjTra8E8hu0O7GvuczGfA9NiONmxbglgKK58/QVYdlsZUiGTaWkkY
>   4nMHiaFe9TiPQ6W2vMGutLFR3V6YSshchCskl6cP1OdaIXCYgzZKIjUWHePzd/ds
>   zCZeNqul1N7iIQ0L5lfSGgfB2eDeeK3JKFjetrrbJQXz0+XeTZLPMSMr6W5Ggq3l
>   PnoJVTrxUd3b2WKgR4FZB+imYRWEz5KLnB5ZVedC+fU24bECcNptrTQaZZUWnR3Z
>   ABJqz8avBrNV0Jf9BaFRxcWkrWyr4KtxDArxXOuMHNvGVtj+hhPZcPGj3N9Xam3E
>   6snAGebIiAEivZPYLVVVk0lZW2H0ISwkKkjD8qs7h8wa7Qbchp2K5IyENEzi20oe
>   FNRoCwHyjsCY0nECHCG3WON0EXG2DZDTvA17OoyfuKnRT09FVt3OOEPTV048vUid
>   kUoGa7uT7ud9En7uNSfmDpw+xHxB38N986BKBtoeJlGgDYISJkIgr40TIKMLE/Yc
>   whDnmKxT68dfSGcv/DIUzYs+d/OBzSpHIWK87me5QnhmLTQ1xwfwtFoTyk6B3Vzx
>   ljlZFD6e7PJfjo/RIhb0zMvtBvRTONRrMXKRdRY=
>   =serM
>   -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
>
> boundary2----extKDvsqGExTQI2WVuplHFCUQJ3XVL--
>
> --DM1-Sb0636VXPQNO3412Ygegb9suqr--

***Embedded content from Map:***

> boundary2----extKDvsqGExTQI2WVuplHFCUQJ3XVL
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="version" Content-Type: application/pgp-encrypted Content-Length:
>   10
>
> Version: 1
>
> boundary2----extKDvsqGExTQI2WVuplHFCUQJ3XVL
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload" Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length:
>   1118
>
> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- Version: BCPG v1.47
>
> hQIOA8aa0/bci2e/EAf/fkgOBK+cOoeY+44htcvjE9Sxk9RK73aOEaxDOBNqFOsV
>   Nzw1va7cc7wzYOTlHhZV/MkpXq+IrZV316moJu1EAhscN9YmyReVDOzrkzZ1hBmq
>   V2MlAr5/CRqS7nQEmCqy/Mz0STtAPZNg3FOh8F79dJnRws5/SdW+zvn2MoSvGTs3
>   0YvjmtPq2YyVkMlAvJ62f903UYNIiAcEe1k8gWDVW9LJ4tGud+8H0bsG8EFWPsSI
>   b5rON+MKGykbWGnbSrOy9cqslJaghj91r7ZbsXXXiRn9v4rpOardfiBEnoamI5Tz
>   jfDKESnr7CqoZgb62je+NJrB5puoAwy8LTynXx4cmQgAnf8lb6f+mIxa1U1Mu6iR
>   KNTjrH83Cx2BjTra8E8hu0O7GvuczGfA9NiONmxbglgKK58/QVYdlsZUiGTaWkkY
>   4nMHiaFe9TiPQ6W2vMGutLFR3V6YSshchCskl6cP1OdaIXCYgzZKIjUWHePzd/ds
>   zCZeNqul1N7iIQ0L5lfSGgfB2eDeeK3JKFjetrrbJQXz0+XeTZLPMSMr6W5Ggq3l
>   PnoJVTrxUd3b2WKgR4FZB+imYRWEz5KLnB5ZVedC+fU24bECcNptrTQaZZUWnR3Z
>   ABJqz8avBrNV0Jf9BaFRxcWkrWyr4KtxDArxXOuMHNvGVtj+hhPZcPGj3N9Xam3E
>   6snAGebIiAEivZPYLVVVk0lZW2H0ISwkKkjD8qs7h8wa7Qbchp2K5IyENEzi20oe
>   FNRoCwHyjsCY0nECHCG3WON0EXG2DZDTvA17OoyfuKnRT09FVt3OOEPTV048vUid
>   kUoGa7uT7ud9En7uNSfmDpw+xHxB38N986BKBtoeJlGgDYISJkIgr40TIKMLE/Yc
>   whDnmKxT68dfSGcv/DIUzYs+d/OBzSpHIWK87me5QnhmLTQ1xwfwtFoTyk6B3Vzx
>   ljlZFD6e7PJfjo/RIhb0zMvtBvRTONRrMXKRdRY=
>   =serM
>
> -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
>
> boundary2----extKDvsqGExTQI2WVuplHFCUQJ3XVL--

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but I'd suggest to DEBUG the code in the `MultipartAwareFormHttpMessageConverter.readMultipart()`. That is a place where an `UploadedMultipartFile` appears.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the `CommonsMultipartResolver` seems to indicate it doesn't support nested multiparts.

It might not be too hard to subclass it and override `parseRequest()`, but you might have to dig into `commons-fileupload` as well.

**EDIT**

Regarding multipart response:

I just [patched the http sample](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/e5da71bf84a7ccd2b7b03e74fe5f515506ad8164) and found that, as long as the request has a proper `accept` header, simply returning a `MultiValueMap` "just works".

If you need more control over the part headers, you would need to subclass the `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter` and override `getHttpEntity()` to insert extra headers and configure the gateway to use the custom adapter. Basic headers work ok, though - this...

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("foo", "Hello");
map.add("bar", "baz");
map.add("fiz", "qux".getBytes());
return map;
```

...results in this...

```
--6_zk8PXoaiUO_By2XJuUpjs5CEEnYM-wj0qE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 5

Hello
--6_zk8PXoaiUO_By2XJuUpjs5CEEnYM-wj0qE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bar"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 3

baz
--6_zk8PXoaiUO_By2XJuUpjs5CEEnYM-wj0qE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fiz"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 3

qux
--6_zk8PXoaiUO_By2XJuUpjs5CEEnYM-wj0qE--
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. As suggested i have subclassed CommonsMultipartResolver  and overriden parseRequest() and am now able to support a nested multipart.

Comment: As a follow up I am using a an http inbound channel adapter with a custom multipartResolver. I need to respond to the request with a mulipart. Can you recommend an approach to do that?

Comment: That's exactly what i need thanks. The response will be of type "multipart/signed" so I have created a new MessageConverter to handle it. However, the HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway is using the request accept headers to to check if the converter canWrite instead of the content-type which i override in the chain. I tried overriding Accept in the header enricher but that does not appear to work.

Comment: No; it uses the `accept` header from the original request not the value in the reply (because it represents what the client said it could accept). That's why (in my test case) I had to change the client side to set the accept header properly in the request; the converter wouldn't convert when the inbound accept was `*/*`. Of course, in a custom converter, you can choose to return true to `canWrite` regardless (but you're trusting the client can handle it).

Comment: @GaryRussell How do you handle/receive the "fiz" part? Using multipart file like following? 

@RequestPart("fiz") MultipartFile file

Comment: I don't think Spring has anything to help decode a multipart response on the client side, but I could be wrong. HTTP is not my forte. You might have to hack the server-side stuff.